# Error al intentar trabajar aplicación con Python y Flask

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

Intentando instalar el entorno virtual para un curso recibi este error no se porque es:

> virtualenv : El término 'virtualenv' no se reconoce como nombre de un
> cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si
> escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso,
> compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.

```
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ virtualenv -p python3 env
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Estoy tomando el curso Mi primera aplicación web con Python y Flask si pueden ayudarme les agradezco.

Comment: `virtualenv` es un módulo externo que se debe instalar. Desde la linea de comandos: `python -m pip install virtualenv`. Recomendado instalar antes el módulo wheel `python -m pip install wheel`. Más información [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html)